# Flutter : PageView.builder to another page

Tags: flutter, user-interface, navigation

I want to use PageView.Builder in flutter to navigating page to the another page. How to implement it into my code?

Here is my code

```
...      
List<StatefulWidget> pages = [
        HomePage(),
        ListDoaPage(),
        QiblatPage(),
        FavPage()
      ];
    
      PageController controller = PageController();
    
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            body: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 4,
                controller: controller,
                onPageChanged: (page) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = page;
                  });
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return 
                  // ????
                  ;
                }),
    ...
```

The result that I want might be like this

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your page in itemBuilder:

```
List<StatefulWidget> pages = [
        HomePage(),
        ListDoaPage(),
        QiblatPage(),
        FavPage()
      ];
    
      PageController controller = PageController();
    
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            extendBody: true,
            body: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: 4,
                controller: controller,
                onPageChanged: (page) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = page;
                  });
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return pages[position];
                }),
```

Comment: oh woowww, just put it after return :D Thank you very much Jim !